# KnockoutJS 3.3.0 binding seems to be delayed until I press ENTER

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, visual-studio-2013

This is a weird one.

Here is my view:

```
<table class="SelectedPerson">
    <tr><td>Emp ID</td><td><input data-bind="value : EmpID, event : { keypress : loadJson }" type="text" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Net ID</td><td><input data-bind="value : NetID, event : { keypress : loadJson }" type="text" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input data-bind="value : FirstName, event : { keypress : loadJson }" type="text" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

and my results

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>EmployeeID</td>
            <td>NetID</td>
            <td>FirstName</td>
            <td>LastName</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="PersonListViewModel" data-bind="foreach : people">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text : EmpID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text : NetID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text : FirstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text : LastName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my ViewModel

```
    var ViewModel = function (EmpID, NetID, FirstName) {
        var self = this;
        self.EmpID = ko.observable(EmpID);
        self.NetID = ko.observable(NetID);
        self.FirstName = ko.observable(FirstName);
        self.people = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.loadJson = function (data, event) {
            var objectify = ko.toJS(self);
            console.log(objectify.EmpID);
            if (event.which == 13) {
                var objectify = ko.toJS(self);
                console.log(objectify.EmpID);
                console.log(ko.toJSON(self));

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '/Home/GetRecords',
                    data: {
                        "json": ko.toJSON(data)
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.people(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });

            }

            return true;
        };
    };

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

It talks to a C# method which accepts the JSON in as a parameter and returns the results based on what you enter. That bit works fine in isolation.

However here is what happens:
Imagine this database

```
[
{"EmpID":"123", "FirstName":"Jim"},
{"EmpID":"124", "FirstName":"Bob"}
]
```

1. Type 123 in EmpID field
2. Press Enter
3. No Results
4. Press Enter again
5. Correct Result ie Jim displayed in results as firstname match
6. Change EmpID to 124
7. Press Enter
8. Same Result ie Jim still displayed in results as firstname match
9. Press Enter again
10. Correct Result ie Bob displayed in results as firstname match.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are records returned correctly from server?

Comment: yes they are. The C# bit is working fine and it actually loads into my view - except its one Enter press behind. ps ignore all the console.logs - thats me trying to test values...it misbehaves with or without those in code.

Comment: For me it seems like it is not passing first check of event.which == 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `keyup` event. The reason that you are one key behind is that the model hasn't updated.

```
<table class="SelectedPerson">
    <tr>
        <td>Emp ID</td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value : EmpID, event : { keyup : loadJson }" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Net ID</td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value : NetID, event : { keyup : loadJson }" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value : FirstName, event : { keyup : loadJson }" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/w7c596L0/

Comment: you beauty! Thanks :):):):) do you know how long i was literally getting knocked out! by that!?